# SkipLimitStepFactoryBean is missing from Spring Batch 2.2.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am migrating from Spring Batch 1.1.4 to Spring Batch 2.2.7 and I am seeing [`SkipLimitStepFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/1.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/SkipLimitStepFactoryBean.html) is missing from new library.

I got this link - http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/58139-skiplimitstepfactorybean-missing-in-spring-batch-2-0-0-m3 which says that it has been renamed to [`FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/factory/FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean.html).

However, when I see this class [`FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/factory/FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean.html), it doesn't have [`setFatalExceptionClasses(java.lang.Class[])`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/1.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/SkipLimitStepFactoryBean.html#setFatalExceptionClasses(java.lang.Class[])) method which I want to configure. Anybody knows how to do this?

Here is how the bean in configured in Spring Batch 1.1.4 jobs.xml

```
<bean id="loadbaseListSkipLimitStep"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SkipLimitStepFactoryBean"
        parent="loadbaseListStep" 
        abstract="true">
    <property name="skipLimit" value="0" />
    <property name="retryPolicy" ref="recoverableExceptionRetryPolicy" />
    <property name="backOffPolicy" ref="timedBackoffPolicy" />
    <property name="fatalExceptionClasses" value="org.springframework.jms.JmsException, org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Because everything is fatal, unless you specify it as a skippable exception. Also why aren't you simply using the namespace to configure things instead of manually configure each/every bean.

Comment: I didn't get the part - "Manually configuring each/every bean"? Also, can you post it as answer.

Comment: You are configuring beans by hand if you know/need to add a `FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean`. Instead use the xml namespace to configure your steps/jobs as this hides this fact a little and saves you from configuring all the infrastructure beans by hand.

Comment: I updated the question to provide the XML structure of the bean as part of Spring Batch 1.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum),

> Because everything is fatal, unless you specify it as a skippable
>   exception.

So, my XML configuration changes as below.

```
<bean id="loadbaseListSkipLimitStep"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SkipLimitStepFactoryBean"
        parent="loadbaseListStep" 
        abstract="true">
    <property name="skipLimit" value="0" />
    <property name="retryPolicy" ref="recoverableExceptionRetryPolicy" />
    <property name="backOffPolicy" ref="timedBackoffPolicy" />
</bean>
```